# How to develop an Android application for a custom device?

Tags: android

I'm a fairly basic android developer. I wrote a few apps for WearOS, nothing incredibly complex so far. A potential client wants me to develop an application for a custom device they have. Some sort of round screen the size of a kitchen watch (I don't have physical access to the device as it's remote work). At first I thought it would not be too hard as I have experience with wear devices. The thing is that I have absolutely no idea how to write an app for a custom device. They gave me several techical specs (exact screen size, Android version required, RAM, supported ABI (arm64-v8a), etc. But I only know how to build for predefined Android devices listed in Android Studio.

How am I supposed to handle such a project?

Some follow-up questions:

- Is it correct to say that their device runs a **custom Android rom**?
- Let's say I start developping their product as if it was for a WearOS device (that's the closest from the list of predefined emulators). Am I right in assuming that eventually, once I know how to setup the proper build for their device, most of the code will remain the same, modulo some minor adptations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that their device runs a custom Android rom?

No, I don't think so. I assume that is running a regular android version (You said they gave to you the specific version) but the screen its round.

> Let's say I start developping their product as if it was for a WearOS device (that's the closest from the list of predefined emulators). Am I right in assuming that eventually, once I know how to setup the proper build for their device, most of the code will remain the same, modulo some minor adptations?

In my oppinion, like I said, it's very likely that the device is running a "normal android", so I would suggest to develp the app in that fashion.

Build some simple example App, send it to them to test if it runs OK, you can ask them for some photos to check how it displays on the round screen, and if everything works fine, you can then start building the final app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual device in the emulator with the exact details you have from the customer, then use that for the starting point.